# How to show all Signed in users in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to show all signed in users on the screen. I am using Firebase for authenticating.

These users that i want to show.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in order to get all of the connected users.

Another option is to save your users into a database such as Firebase RealtimeDatabase and fetch the users when you want, just make sure that you save the users' data securely.